# How do I close a socket from another socket in C (using switch)?

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp, openssl

I'm using `select()` along with OPENSSL to open multiple sockets on a generic TCP Server. I have a pretty standard setup using a pool of of file descriptors an then listening on each socket individually using

```
int sd = client_socket[id];
/* Add new socket to array of sockets */
for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++) {
    /* If position is empty */
    if (client_socket[i] == 0) {
        client_socket[i] = new_socket;
        client_ssl_sockets[i] = *ssl; //save ssl object to array
        break;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is issue a command from a client to force close another client's socket. I'm currently using

```
void kill_socket(int id) {
    close(client_socket[id]);
    client_socket[id] = 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the above just closes my socket - even if I supply no ID argument. Is there another way to be able to reference a specific socket in the pool of sockets to isolate and close it with an issued command?

Clarification Edit:
When I say a command issued by another client I mean a text string being taken in via SSL_read and then being used by a switch statement as such:

```
ret_status = SSL_read(ssl, buf, MAX_BUF);

strncpy(pre, buf, 2); /* Pull first 2 characters of buffer */
strcpy(var, buf + 2); /* Pull rest of characters from buffer for function argument (where applicable) */

cmd = atoi(pre); /* Convert buffer prefix to integer for switch */

switch (cmd) {
    ...
}
```

Then I can have a client execute a command (and even pass an argument into the function with the `var` string above.

The problem as I see it is that the `close()` function is being called inside the `for` loop responsible for that specific socket and can't see the other sockets. How do I make a socket visible (and interactive) to other sockets?

EDIT: Switch statement calling the `kill_socket()` function as requested by @Remy

```
case 98: /* Disconnect node */
    if (check_auth(client_ip[i]) == 1) {
        printf("Closing client connection!\n\n");
        kill_socket(atoi(var));
     } else {
        printf("You must authenticate first!\n\n");
     }

     break;
```

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of [shutdown(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) but your question is *very* unclear.

Comment: First try writing a small example that demonstrates the problem without SSL.

Comment: "*even if I supply no ID argument*" - that is not possible given the code shown. In any case, clients have no concept of socket IDs, that is strictly private to your code. So how you are determining which socket ID to close? Presumably you have associated your own unique ID (client usernamae, etc) to each socket, and clients are able to request those IDs, which you then use to lookup the actual socket IDs. Is that right? If not, that is what you *should* be doing.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can you elaborate on how my question is unclear? I have multiple clients connecting in to a central server. I want to be able to force a client to disconnect from a different client.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would tend to agree with you however it does work. I just don't know why.

Comment: @tehOJ:  "*it does work*" - what works? Calling `kill_socket()` without an ID value? That is not possible given the code shown. The parameter is required. Which goes back to my question - how are you determining which socket ID to close? Please show that code. Otherwise, your question is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: You cannot *force* a client on a different machine to do anything.  The most you can do is send it a signal of some kind, and hope that it understands and honors your request.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: a client sends a command to the *server*, and the *server* then closes the requested client socket.  The requesting client is not telling another client to disconnect.

Comment: I still don't see any *forcing* going on in that sequence of events, @RemyLebeau.  I am perhaps being too picky about details of wording, but wording anomalies sometimes betray misconceptions or wrong expectations.

Comment: The only way you could call `kill_socket` without an ID is if there's no declaration visible for `kill_socket` from where it was called, in which case you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the implicit declaration `int kill_socket()` doesn't match the definition `void kill_socket(int id)`.

Comment: We need to see how `kill_socket` is being called.

Comment: `kill_socket()` added above. @JohnBollinger I apologize for the confusion but yes, @RemyLebeau is correct. I'm trying to close the local socket not force the client to do anything. I'm trying to terminate the socket on the server side.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question body to explain the behavior you are observing. Right now, the problems could be: (1) your array has the wrong values in them; (2) you are passing the wrong value to your function; (3) the client command is wrong; (4) the client command was parsed incorrectly by the server; (5) your server is closing the connection to your client for an unrelated reason; (6) a combination of the above; (7) some other unforseen reason. If you provide a complete example, there will be a higher chance the problem can be identified.

Comment: @jxh We're talking 460 lines of code in the core.c file alone. Plus two other .c files along with their respective header files. I'm trying to show what I (in my admittedly limited wisdom) think is relevant to show what I'm trying to get at. Is there another way I should show the code?

Comment: @tehOJ: Yes, my original suggestion of writing a small example that demonstrates the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @tehOJ: the code shown requires clients to know each other's socket IDs. How are they getting those values? Those IDs should be private to the server code only and NOT known to the remote parties, unless you have implemented a command that allows clients to retreive a list of available socket IDs, which is bad design. Clients should login with a unique ID, and the server keep track of those login IDs and associated socket IDs. Then a client can send a command to request a given login ID be closed, and the server can lookup the actual socket ID to close.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "socket ID" as defined in the code above is a bit of a misnomer I think. I'm passing a single integer that corresponds with the index of the `int client_socket[MAX_CONNECTIONS]` array of file descriptors. And now rubber ducking with you I'm thinking that's my issue. Does each socket have some type of serialized ID number that I should be calling there?

Comment: @tehOJ: by "socket ID", I'm referring to the socket file descriptor. `close()` requires a socket file descriptor as input. `kill_socket()` takes an array index as input, and uses that index to retrieve a socket descriptor from the array and pass it to `close()`. Your command handler is getting that index directly from the client's command input. So how is the client getting those array indexes in the first place? How does it know which client is located at which array index? How does it even know about the array in the first place? Bad design.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm storing a list of connected clients using sqlite3. A properly authenticated client can pull the list of currently connected clients which looks like this:  1  |  10.96.113.230  |  (null)
2  |  10.96.113.242  |  (null)

Comment: You would need to expose the array of sockets somehow so that the client can select the proper index and indicate that that index from your array of sockets is the one that you want to shut down.

Comment: @tehOJ: The list of clients stored in the DB (why are you doing that?) may not match the list of clients stored in the array in memory. This is a VERY bad design. I stick by my earlier suggestion. You should require the clients to login to the server (how are they authenticated? You might already have this), and store those login IDs with the socket descriptors they belong to. Then, when requested, you can find the socket descriptor that belongs to a specified login ID, regardless of where it is located in the array.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok I'll do some more reading/research and see what I can come up with. Thank you to everyone for all the help and advice!

Comment: 1. Zero is a valid socket descriptor (although it normally refers to standard input). You should use -1 instead. 2. You don't seem to have any checks in your code, so guessing about the source of misbehaviour is pretty much useless: it could be anywhere. 3. You use `atoi()` to parse the user command parameter. You should use e.g. `strtol()` with proper error checking (including that the entire parameter was converted) instead. 4. As Remy Lebeau mentioned, you only have at most a few tens of thousands of clients, which can definitely stay in memory; no need for a DB.